# How to bind tmux command to Alt-<x>, not M-<x>?

Tags: tmux

The problem with `bind -n M-x` is that it binds not only to Alt-x but also Esc-x. I want the command to execute only on Alt-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On most terminals, the keys <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd> send the exact same sequence – an `ESC` followed by a `x`.

*Some* terminals have an option of setting the highest bit instead of adding the `ESC` prefix.  For example, this is the default in Xterm. In that case, you could try inputting a literal 0xF8 (`x` with the high bit set) in your configuration. However, it's very likely that tmux will look for a `M-x` keybinding anyway, ignoring your 0xF8.